# How to make a html text ends with 3 dots in JLabel

Tags: html, formatting, jlabel

By default, JLabel do this formatting for simple text.

```
setText("Hello World!");
setMaximumSize(new Dimension(30, 20);
```

This will be displayed like:

```
Hello Wo...
```

But in case we're using html formatting:

```
setText("<html><p color='#333333'>Hello World!</p></html>");
setMaximumSize(new Dimension(30, 20);
```

It will be displayed like:

```
Hello Worl
```

and the rest text is just cutted off.

Is there any way to make text have the same view as in first (text...) case?

Label's width is changing and html formatting much more complicated (so it is impossible to use fontmetrics and will be complicate to select simple text).

Thanks in advance!